# Is any government considering taxing remote work more than "regular" work?

Tags: economy, taxes

[Deutsche Bank proposed a 5% tax for remote work](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/11/12/deutsche-bank-proposes-a-5percent-tax-for-remote-workers-post-pandemic.html) as remote workers enjoy several benefits such as more safety (e.g. from COVID), reduced costs due to less traveling and less socializing.

> A research team at Deutsche Bank proposed that people pay a 5% tax for
> the “privilege” of working from home, if they continue to do so after
> the pandemic, as **this could subsidize income lost by lower-earners due
> to the coronavirus crisis**.
>
> Working from home meant that many people were saving on everyday costs
> such as travel, lunch, clothes and cleaning, as well as possibly
> spending less on socializing. However, the report also said it meant
> remote workers were “contributing less to the infrastructure of the
> economy whilst still receiving its benefits.”

This sounds similar to a [solidarity tax](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/solidarity-tax), as remote workers become solitary with those who cannot work remotely.

**Question:** Is any government considering taxing remote work more than "regular" work?

Comment: Would an answer count if such a policy was already in place or are you only looking for governments that are considering (but have not implemented) such a policy?

Comment: @EkadhSingh It would be even better.